# Not working Python miliseconds time

Tags: python, datetime, time, floating-point, format

I have read all posts in Stackoverflow, documentation for "time" in python docs, but not found how to make float time.

```
 import time
 time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f', time.gmtime(60.5))
```

returns 00:01:00.%f

I want take  00:01:00.500

I wasn't able to find similar question.

Final solution is:

```
 datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(60.5).strftime('%H:%M:%S')+'.'+str(int(int(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(60.5).strftime('%f'))/1000))
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have read all posts in Stackoverflow? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time` module does *not* support the `%f` millisecond formatter because the [`time.struct_time` tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) doesn't support milliseconds.

The `datetime` module **does** support milliseconds. Use that module instead:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(60.5).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Demo:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(60.5).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')
'00:01:00.500000'
```

Comment: How implement miliseconds, not microseconds (ms/1000) (maybe here exists any format literal)?

Comment: @xercool: There are no other format literals; datetime objects store subsecond info as miliseconds, and you can only use the `%f` formatter to display those. You'll have to extract that information yourself and format it differently.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `%f` are microseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime 
'{:%H:%M:%S.%f}'.format(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(60.5))
```

returns

```
00:01:00.500000
```

Comment: But the `time.strftime()` format doesn't support it, only `datetime.datetime.strftime()` (and by extension, `format()`).

Comment: And you can use `format(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(60.5), '%H:%M:%S.%f')` and forgo the rest of the string templating.

Comment: And just use `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(60.5).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')` since that is what `datetime.__format__()` calls anyway.

Comment: How implement miliseconds (not micro)?